# Magento 1.9.X - category page title

Tags: magento-1.9, category, page-title

How to get Magento category page title in frontend? 
Already tried:

```
<?php if ($category->getPageTitle()):?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getPageTitle(), 'page_title') ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

[image]

Comment: yes as suggested in mage i want to display here page title

Comment: plz show which error are display? or plz show full code

Comment: hi @Payaljhamta, may i know what kind search box you are using

Comment: You have a typo here $category, and $_category->getPageTitle(). And Page Title field would be appearing there as meta title

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a typo here (if you have created `page_title` attribute) :

Replace `<?php if ($category->getPageTitle()):?>` WITH `<?php if ($_category->getPageTitle()):?>`

If you want to get `meta_title` (this is shown as `Page Title` in category edit page at admin)

[image]

then use :

```
<?php if ($_category->getMetaTitle()):?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getMetaTitle(), 'meta_title') ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Comment: yes as suggested in mage i want to display here page title  so i can add this code in head.html

Comment: updated the code/answer

Comment: these page title i want to display in frontend as i mentioned in our qustion

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController`

add below code in `viewAction` after `$this->loadLayoutUpdates();` code

```
<?php if ($category->getMetaTitle()):?>    
       <?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__($category->getMetaTitle())); ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

[How to rewrite controller](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-overriding-in-magento-controllers--cms-23386)

Comment: these page title i want to display in frontend as i mentioned in my qustion

Comment: Updated answer please check it

Comment: Please make me clear which file i have to add code

Comment: updated answer check it

Comment: Please make me clear where i have add code i.e in which file so that Page title display as per i mentioned in image that i attached in mu question plesae